# How to use greater than and less than in a single if statement in Java

Tags: java

I made a BMI calculator. One of the things I have to do is add categories using if statements. 18.5 to 24.9 normal weight so that would be one of the categories.

This is the way I have tried to do it.

```
else if ( (bmi >18.5) && (<24.9))
```

Obviously this won't work for me, what way should I write this I feel like there is a way to write 18.5 to 24.9 instead of using greater than or equal to but I honestly don't even know what to look up.

Link to code http://pastebin.com/gNE7VwE1

Comment: `if ( (bmi >18.5) && (bmi <24.9))` Unfortunately, there isn't a simpler solution in java than to rewrite a second expression. Show use your full code, there may be a simpler way to write this.

Comment: `if((bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9))`

Comment: Thanks guy's for your time i'll edit my question up top and add a link to paste bin if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
if ( bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
```

Unfortunately, Java does not support a '**BETWEEN**' operator (like what *SQL* does e.g).

Comment: Thanks a million worked perfect. So i was just missing adding bmi in again.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own method to check if between,

```
public static boolean isBetween(int low, int high, int bmi) {
    return high > low ? bmi > low && bmi < high : bmi > high && bmi < low;
}
```

Comment: I seen this method when i was searching on google and searching on here before i posted my Q. Honestly I have only started learning java a couple of months and i have no idea what that is. Where in my code would i place that and would you have any links that would explain this more. Thanks.