# how to write range for a variable in if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, range

i want to make a project that will use if statement for my problem please see the picture::
If the user enter a height of the window between 20_21.99 and the width of between 14_15.99 it will show the number of balance you should use is number 3.

so in the if statement can i write if(hight is betweent 20 and 21.99) (width is between 14 and 15.99)[ balance= 3; system.out.println(balance);

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter hight ");
double hight= scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("please enter width");
double width=scan.nextDouble();
double balance=0;    

if(hight==20 && width==14){
balance=3;
System.out.println("please use balance number " + balance);}
  
  


}
```

OUTPUT//
please enter hight
20
please enter width
14
please use balance number 3.0

the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJa7b.pn

Comment: `if ((width >= 14.0d && width <= 15.99d) && (hight >= 20.0d && hight <= 21.99d)) { balance = 4.0d; }`

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear though what I have understood that balance should be 3, if height and width in range. Have a look at [How to use greater than and less than in a single if statement in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883860/how-to-use-greater-than-and-less-than-in-a-single-if-statement-in-java).

Condition inside if statement should be something like this:

```
if ((height >= 20 && height <= 21.99) && (width >= 14 && width <= 15.99)) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range using brackets to specify the upper and lower limits.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

double height = 0, width = 0, balance = 0; // Declare variables

System.out.println("Please enter height");
height = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("please enter width");
width = scan.nextDouble();

if ((height >= 20.0d && height <= 21.99d) && (width >= 14.0d && width <= 15.99d)) { 
    balance = 4.0d; 
}

System.out.println("Please use balance number " + balance);
```